# How to handle inappropriate chat messages?

Tags: support, chat, moderation

The chat FAQ says

> If you see an inappropriate, spam, or offensive chat message, please use the hover menu at the far right of each chat message to flag it. This will draw it to the attention of the community moderators.

Is this guideline correct? I know that "flagging as spam/offensive" notifies multiple users across many rooms. Should I perhaps use another way to ask for removing an inappropriate message?

If the message is unquestionably inappropriate but the flag was invalidated - should I flag it again?

At what point should I use the "flag for moderator" form?

Comment: Perhaps if it's the same user then you can flag one of their post on the site and include a reference, I did it with a rude rejection reason in the documentation and a Mod marked it as helpful

Comment: It depends what you flag. If the message is new/recent (as in posted in the last few minutes, maybe an hour or so) and needs to be gone quickly as it is disturbing the normal operation in a chat room, use the flag option on the far right of the message, that will bring in 10K-ers to assess the situation. If you're going over the transcript and find messages from way-back or stuff that is troublesome but doesn't need immediate removal use the *flag for moderator* option in the LEFT drop down of the message.